Why does setting surface color to white make my BottomAppBar not white?
I have a fresh created small project:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            MaterialTheme(colorScheme = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.copy(surface = Color.Black)){
                BottomAppBar(containerColor = Color.White) {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

As i expected the BottomAppBar has White background because i explicitly specified Color.White:

I see the same result when i specify surface = Color.Blue, surface = Color.Green, surface = Color.Red and any other color. And it is correct because i explicitly specify that containerColor = Color.White. But for some reason when i write surface = Color.Write the BottomAppBar changes its color:

Why?

Please don't double post. You already asked that here: Why isn't BottomAppBar white?

@Leviathan I tried to delete that post to rephrase and create a new one, but I didn't manage

If it's still about the same problem you should always edit your question to update it.

@Leviathan in the previous post you said that you don't have the same problem when trying to use the code from the question. Pls try this case. Do you have the same issue ?

BottomAppBar has a default tonal elevation of 3dp. Tonal elevation shifts the container's color slightly towards the primary color, as explained in the Material 3 design guidelines.
As stated in docs for BottomAppBar, the tonal elevation is only applied if the container color is set to the current colorscheme's surface color (which is the default value).
Since your are specifying white as both your colorscheme's surface color, as well as the BottomAppbar's containerColor, the above contition is met. So tonal elevation is applied and turns your white slightly blue-ish (which is your colorscheme's primary color).

Thank you a lot. I set BottomAppBar's tonal elevation to 0 and it has got white. But i have a question. Why doesn't BottomAppBar get totally white, when i change the primary color to white? https://snipboard.io/tBKfQ3.jpg

I have found the answer. For some reason tonal elevation shifts not to primary color but to surfaceTint
